# Finishing An If Statement

Tags: jquery

This is a quick question.

```
<table id="menuStructuresPageList" class="rounded-corner dataTablePageList">

if ($('.dataTablePageList')) {
```

What I want to do is do an if statement that says if the object that has a class of dataTablesPageList also has a id of menuStructuresPageList then ....

But I'm not sure how I would complete the tail end of the if statement.

EDIT:

The point I'm making is this is shared code with many tables so all tables have the class of dataTablePageList but if one of them has the id of a menuStructuresPageList then it needs to do the if part of the statement.

```
if ($('.dataTablePageList')) {

} else {

var oTable = $('.dataTablePageList').dataTable( {
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "aoColumnDefs": [ 
            { "sWidth": "20px", "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
            { "sWidth": "40px", "aTargets": [ -1 ] },
            { "sWidth": "40px", "aTargets": [ -2 ] },
            { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
            { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ -1] },
            { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ -2 ] },
            { "sClass": "center", "aTargets": [ 0 ] }, 
            { "sClass": "center", "aTargets": [ -1 ] },
            { "sClass": "center", "aTargets": [ -2 ] }  
        ]
});
}
```

Comment: It would help you to read up on css selectors: http://htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/selectors/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [`.hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

```
if (!$('#menuStructuresPageList').hasClass('dataTablePageList')) {
    ...
```

EDIT: You mean you want two branches within the `if`?

```
if ($(this).hasClass('.dataTablePageList')) {

    // do something
    if(this.id == "menuStructuresPageList" ) {

        // do something
    }

} else {
      ...
```

Comment: @Jeff Davidson - Please see my edit. (eek, and my re-edit! and my re-re-edit!)

Comment: Let me try and explain this again. ALL my tables have the dataTablesPageList class. ALL of them. However if the table has an id of menuStructuresPageList then I want it to do something instead of the else part.

Comment: Why is this solution better than putting both items in the selector like this: `if ($('#menuStructuresPageList.dataTablePageList')) {` and letting the selector engine do all the work as I proposed in my answer?

Comment: @jfriend00 because jQuery will always return an object and an object will always be true.

Comment: OK, how it it better than 'if ($('#menuStructuresPageList.dataTablePageList').length > 0)'

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if($("#menuStructuresPageList.dataTablesPageList").length){
 // your code
}
```

or

```
if($("#menuStructuresPageList").hasClass("dataTablesPageList")){
 // your code
}
```

Comment: I apologized I didn't explain it more check my updated page edit in a second.

Comment: Read my edit about dealing with multiple tables so I'm looking to see if the table has an id of something specific.

Comment: @Jeff: By the time I checked the edit Karim has already answered it in the best possible way. Pls chk tht

Answer (score 1):

If you want only an object that has both the specified ID and class, then you can put them both in the jQuery selector specification like this:

```
if ($('#menuStructuresPageList.dataTablePageList').length > 0) {
   // found object with id="menuStructuresPageList" and class="dataTablePageList"
} else {
   // didn't find object with both class and id as specified
}
```

Putting them together in the selector with no space between them means that the same object must have both.